# SharePoint SSE : customize SharePoint libraries alert emails

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-alerts

In previous SharePoint versions it was possible to customize list and libraries emails alerts (cf https://lionadi.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/sharepoint-2013-email-alerts-with-wrong-urls-under-extended-zones/ ) . Unfortunately the command stsadm is not available anymore in SharePoint SSE; moreover Microsoft documentation does not provide anything on par with "stsadm -o updatealerttemplates".
Is there another way to perform that please?

Regards,